# Actualizar registro en un modal php

Tags: php, ajax, modal

mi duda es que quiero actualizar los registros de la base de datos en un modal, el problema que por mucho que le de al botón de actualizar no me hace nada y directamente se queda hay la pantalla del modal y ya esta, ¿que debo hacer?

```
 <!-- modal-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Actualizar cliente</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="update_client" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]  ?>" method="POST">
                    <?php foreach (get_client_id() as $f) { ?>
                        <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $f["id"] ?>" name="id">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $f["Nombre"] ?>" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Apellidos</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" value="<?php echo $f["Apellidos"] ?>" placeholder="Ingrese sus apellidos">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Teléfono</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="telefono" value="<?php echo $f["Telefono"] ?>" placeholder="Ingrese su telefono">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Correo</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control text-muted" name="correo" value="<?php echo $f["Correo"] ?>" placeholder="Ingrese su correo">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Dirección</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccion" value="<?php echo $f["Dirección"] ?>" placeholder="Ingrese su direccion">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>DNI</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dni" value="<?php echo $f["DNI"] ?>" placeholder="Ingrese su dni">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Población</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="poblacion" value="<?php echo $f["Población"] ?>" placeholder="Ingrese su poblacion">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Edad</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="edad" value="<?php echo $f["Edad"] ?>" placeholder="Ingrese su edad">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <!-- <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update"> -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="update">Actualizar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>

                        </div>
                        <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
                       
                     </div> -->
                </form>
            <?php
                    }
            ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tengo su funcion de actualizar que en teoria funciona perfectamente ya que he conseguido recoger su id, el problema es que desde que le puse un form ya no me hace nada
Funcion update:

```
function update_client()
```

{
$conexion = conexionBBDD();

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$dni = $_POST['dni'];
$poblacion = $_POST['poblacion'];
$edad = $_POST['edad'];

$update = "UPDATE usuarios 
SET Nombre= '$nombre',Apellidos='$apellidos',Telefono=$telefono,Correo='$correo',Dirección='$direccion',
DNI='$dni',Población='$poblacion',Edad=$edad WHERE id = $id";
echo $update;
$resultado = $conexion->query($update);

if ($resultado) {
    echo "<script>Cambiado con exito</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>Error</script>";
}
```

}

En un futuro lo quiero hacer con AJAX peor primero quiero que funcione normal y luego meterla AJAX vi por ahí que había momentos que tenia que activar el modal por que tampoco me lo mostraba y de momento lo tengo así

```
 // Actualizar clientes
$('.update').on('click', function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    //     var actualizar_client = $('#update_client').serialize();
    //     $.ajax({
    //         type: 'POST',
    //         url: 'ajax.php',
    //         data: actualizar_client,
    //         sucess: function (r) {
    //             console.log(r)
    //             if (r == 1) {
    //                 alert("hola");

    //             } else {
    //                 alert("error");
    //             }
    //         }
    //     });
    // });

})
```

Tengo comentado lo del AJAX por ahora mismo hasta que no me funcione normal lo quiero sin AJAX, solo tengo de memento activado el modal pero cuando le doy a actualizar no me hace nada

Comment: ya revisaste si la dirección del action esta bien ?   es decir   action="actualizar.php"

Comment: Demomento como no quiero utilizar AJAX hasta que funcione bien todo está comentado